# Load JSON into Firestore - data types

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Native JSON only supports string, number, boolean. Firestore supports additional types - timestamp, geopoint, date/time. How should you format the JSON to load these data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some information about supported datatypes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

As well as an example:

```
var docData = {
    stringExample: "Hello world!",
    booleanExample: true,
    // Note that numbers can be either integers or floating point
    numberExample: 3.14159265,
    // JSON representation as RFC 3339 String with timezone Z
    // e.g. 1815-12-10T00:00:00.000Z
    dateExample: new Date("December 10, 1815"),
    arrayExample: [5, true, "hello"],
    nullExample: null,
    objectExample: {
        a: 5,
        b: {
            nested: "foo"
        }
    },
    // JSON object w/ latitude and longitude keys
    geoPointExample: {
      latitude: 37.773972
      longitude: -122.431297
    },
    // FIRESTORE GEOPOINT 
    geoPointExample2: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(37.7739,-122.4312)


    // Blobs are base64 encoded strings
    blobExample: "RmlyZXN0b3JlIGlzIGF3ZXNvbWUh"
};
```

More info on protobuf to JSON is available here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not really across how protobuf fits in here but will help working through it.

Comment: You should use the native type from your client with the firestore interface, e.g. to insert a date from node or javascript, use a `new Date()`, from python use a `datetime()` object